# C# Iterate Through deserialised Json Object Insert Less Records to sql

Tags: c#, json, sql-server-2008, iteration

I have made a small c# procedure that reads a deserialized JSON and iterates it.

While Iterating I  have an insert function that inserts each JSON record in a table.

The problem I  am facing is while I Itarete the JSON . The records inserted are less than the actual JSON  objects.

My code is this
//Code for Iterating

```
foreach (ContractsAutoView Contract in ConResponce.Contracts)
{ bool Check = AllMethods.ChecKContractExists(ConnectToERP, 
                             Convert.ToString(Contract.ContractNumber));
  if (Check != true)
  {
    int InsResult = AllMethods.InsertContractsToErp(ConnectToERP, Contract);
    if (InsResult == 1)
    {  RecordResult = RecordResult + "AA: " + Convert.ToString(i) + "Το 
            συμβόλαιο  με Κωδικό " + Contract.ContractNumber + " Ενημέρωσε 
            την Βάση Δεδομένων " + System.Environment.NewLine;
    }  
    else
    {  RecordResult = RecordResult + "AA: " + Convert.ToString(i) + "Το 
            συμβόλαιο  με Κωδικό  " + Contract.ContractNumber + " Δεν 
            Ενημέρωσε την Βάση Δεδομένων " + System.Environment.NewLine;
    }
  }                        
  i++;
}
```

//Code for Iterating

// Code for Inserting Record

```
        public static int InsertContractsToErp(SqlConnection Conn, ContractsAutoView contract)
    {
        int RetRes = 1;
        String insertCmd = "Insert into ContractAutoView(ID, BranchID, ContractNumber, EndorsementNumber, RenewalNumber, VoucherPrefix, VoucherNumber, ClientId, Issue, ContractStart, ContractEnd, EffectDate, Status, Notes, NetAmount,FeeAmount,PenaltyAmount ,TotalAmount,PlateNumber, BirthDate, LicenceDate, DurationID, BM, MotorUseID, CoverPacketID, RatingAreaID, PostCode, MotorValue, HP, ConstructionYear, EndorsementType, InsuredName, InsuredAddress, BrandID, Brand, ModelID, Model, TypeID, ColorID, Color, HasABS, HasAirbags, HasAlarm, HasImmobilizer, IsCabrio, IsLiquidGas, IsBrandNew, HasParking, HasHomeOwned, AnnualUse, EmployeeArea, DriversOptions, EngineCC, Weight, WheelBase, ImportToErp) ";
        insertCmd = insertCmd + "values(@ID, @BranchID, @ContractNumber, @EndorsementNumber, @RenewalNumber, @VoucherPrefix, @VoucherNumber, @ClientId, @Issue, @ContractStart, @ContractEnd, @EffectDate, @Status, @Notes, @NetAmount,@FeeAmount,@PenaltyAmount, @TotalAmount, @PlateNumber, @BirthDate, @LicenceDate, @DurationID, @BM, @MotorUseID, @CoverPacketID, @RatingAreaID, @PostCode, @MotorValue, @HP, @ConstructionYear, @EndorsementType, @InsuredName, @InsuredAddress, @BrandID, @Brand, @ModelID, @Model, @TypeID, @ColorID, @Color, @HasABS, @HasAirbags, @HasAlarm, @HasImmobilizer, @IsCabrio, @IsLiquidGas, @IsBrandNew, @HasParking, @HasHomeOwned, @AnnualUse, @EmployeeArea, @DriversOptions, @EngineCC, @Weight, @WheelBase, 10)";

        if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            Conn.Open();
        }
        SqlCommand InsContractCmd = new SqlCommand(insertCmd, Conn);
        try
        { 

          InsContractCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
          if (contract.ID == null)
          {
            InsContractCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = 0;
          }
          else
          {

            InsContractCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = contract.ID;
          };

        InsContractCmd.Parameters.Add("@BranchID", SqlDbType.Int);
        if (contract.BranchID == null)
        {
            InsContractCmd.Parameters["@BranchID"].Value = 0;
        }
        else
        {

            InsContractCmd.Parameters["@BranchID"].Value = contract.BranchID;
        };

      //i do the same thing for all fields on the Inserted record
      // and then i Execute the query

        RetRes = InsContractCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
        catch (Exception e )
        {
            bool Res = InsertErrors(Conn, "Contract", e);
            RetRes = 99;
        }



        return RetRes;



    }
```

// Code for Inserting Record

After Iterating I get a list on my screen for all the succeded iteration. It reports back to me that all data from JSON where iterated but I get inserted fewer records in my table.
Since I use  try catch blocks,  I have also created a small procedure to capture error messages and insert them into a database table But the iteration never hits my catch block in the insert procedure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put a conditional breakpoint on the **}** line after the ` RetRes = InsContractCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` that halts code execution if **RetRes == 0** and work out whats gonng wrong

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is due to empty fields check your json all desire fields have data properly exist or not.

Secondly apply R.E for proper data on json for verification.
Hopefully it help you out.